# Python - Nested Dictionaries - Extracting Values

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, nested

The below nested dictionary stores the number of olympic medals that have been won by various countries in different cities (Beijing,London,Rio). The below code also creates a list with the number of medals that USA has won. Is there a more Pythonic, clean or efficient way to get that list?

```
nested_d = {'Beijing':{'China':51, 'USA':36, 'Russia':22, 'Great Britain':19}, 'London':    {'USA':46, 'China':38, 'Great Britain':29, 'Russia':22}, 'Rio':{'USA':35, 'Great Britain':22, 'China':20, 'Germany':13}}

bei=nested_d["Beijing"]["USA"]
lon=nested_d["London"]["USA"]
rio=nested_d["Rio"]["USA"]

US_count.append(bei)
US_count.append(lon)
US_count.append(rio)
print(US_count)
```

Thank you!

Comment: `US_count = [bei, lon, rio]`?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using list comprehension. We iterate over the keys in `nested_d`, and per key retrieve the value for `'USA'`.

```
print([nested_d[key]['USA'] for key in nested_d])

[36, 46, 35]
```

Note: this does assume 'USA' is available as key in all nested dicts.